# cURL call to web service not working

Tags: php, web-services, curl, restful-url

I am trying to make a simple get call to a .NET RESTful web service at https://salesgenie.com/brandingservice/details?url=att.salesgenie.com  The test page making the cURL call is at https://test-cms.salesgenie.com/wp-content/themes/salesgenie/branding-proxy.php  The web service can be called in the browser but is timing out when called via cURL.  Here is the code from the branding-proxy.php page:

```
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
}       
$url = 'https://salesgenie.com/brandingservice/details?url=att.salesgenie.com';
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
$response = curl_exec($handle);
$code = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($handle);
setcookie('CmsCookie', $code . '    ' . $response, 0, '/', 'salesgenie.com', 0);
echo 'Code:' . $code."<br />Response: ".$response;
```

Comment: Did you try adding the `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` and the `CURLOPT_HEADER` ?

Comment: I've tried HEADER with Content-type and USERAGENT with a made up agent.

Comment: Hmm... I will just run some tests and then post the answer.

Comment: Well it appears that the IP of our test environment server was being blocked from calling into our .NET app by our infrastructure team.  The same code was able to reliably run in our dev and prod environments.  Talk about banging your head against a wall...and then finding out someone put the wall in your way.  *sigh*

Comment: Then I was actually right, in some ways.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the timeout happens while using your links, though I think the problem happens somewhere else. The reason I've come to that conclusion is that I uploaded your code to my own website. It worked fine.

#### Important

If you are the owner of `salesgenie.com` then I think you have a problem with the server, since sometimes the responses I got was either a timeout (code 0), code 200 (with result) or code 320. So the problem might be a problem within the server itself.

#### Tricks

- Try removing the `setcookie` to spare some processing.
- Also try using `http` instead of `https` since `https` requires some more processing to use.

Comment: Well the salesgenie site is forced to https so the call will always get routed to https.  I can take out the cookie for testing purposes, but ultimately that is the purpose of the web serivce call, to pull the branding info and write it to a cookie.

Comment: Well the result I was getting was simple an unstable one, and none consistent.